# Can't get php-webdriver to work

Tags: php, ubuntu, selenium, composer-php, browserstack

I would like to run [automated tests on browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/php#getting-started) which require that the libaries from [github.com/facebook/php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) are installed.

I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04 running Apache2.

I'm following the [Get The Code](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver#getting-the-code) steps from the GitHub repo but when I try to run `php composer.phar install` I get a some warnings that I'm missing packages and extesions.

```
php-webdriver: (master)$ php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.0.0 requires phpdocumentor/template-zend ~1.3 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/template-zend[1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.0.1 requires phpdocumentor/template-zend ~1.3 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/template-zend[1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.1.0 requires phpdocumentor/template-zend ~1.3 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/template-zend[1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.2.0 requires phpdocumentor/template-zend ~1.3 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/template-zend[1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.3.2 requires phpdocumentor/template-zend ~1.3 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/template-zend[1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.4.0 requires phpdocumentor/template-zend ~1.3 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/template-zend[1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.5.0 requires phpdocumentor/template-zend ~1.3 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/template-zend[1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.6.0 requires phpdocumentor/template-zend ~1.3 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/template-zend[1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.6.1 requires phpdocumentor/template-zend ~1.3 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/template-zend[1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.7.0 requires phpdocumentor/template-zend ~1.3 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/template-zend[1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.7.1 requires phpdocumentor/template-zend ~1.3 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/template-zend[1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.8.0 requires phpdocumentor/template-zend ~1.3 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/template-zend[1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.8.1 requires phpdocumentor/template-zend ~1.3 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/template-zend[1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.8.2 requires phpdocumentor/template-zend ~1.3 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/template-zend[1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2].
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.3.1 requires dompdf/dompdf dev-master@dev -> no matching package found.
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor v2.3.0 requires dompdf/dompdf dev-master@dev -> no matching package found.
    - phpdocumentor/template-zend 1.3.2 requires ext-xsl * -> the requested PHP extension xsl is missing from your system.
    - phpdocumentor/template-zend 1.3.1 requires ext-xsl * -> the requested PHP extension xsl is missing from your system.
    - phpdocumentor/template-zend 1.3.0 requires ext-xsl * -> the requested PHP extension xsl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor 2.* -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor[v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.1.0, v2.2.0, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.2, v2.4.0, v2.5.0, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.2].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Perhaps I did not Add the Dependency in the [packagist](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver#packagist) step correctly?  For this step I updated the composer.json file to:

```
{
  "name": "facebook/webdriver",
  "description": "A php client for WebDriver",
  "keywords": ["webdriver", "selenium", "php", "facebook"],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver",
  "type": "library",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/issues",
    "forum": "https://www.facebook.com/groups/phpwebdriver/",
    "source": "https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver"
  },
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.19",
    "facebook/webdriver": "dev-master"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*",
    "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "2.*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": ["lib/"]
  }
}
```

Did I add the `"facebook/webdriver": "dev-master"` line correctly?

I've tried continuing to the [next step](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver#getting-started) and running `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar` but then I get this error in the terminal.

```
php-webdriver: (master)$ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar 
12:21:07.240 INFO - Launching a standalone server
12:21:07.318 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 24.75-b04
12:21:07.318 INFO - OS: Linux 3.13.0-46-generic amd64
12:21:07.390 INFO - v2.45.0, with Core v2.45.0. Built from revision 5017cb8
12:21:07.557 INFO - Default driver org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped: registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}] does not match with current platform: LINUX
12:21:07.656 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
12:21:07.659 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
12:21:07.660 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
12:21:07.666 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
12:21:07.667 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
12:21:07.739 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@2a4c6a7d
12:21:07.739 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
12:21:07.742 WARN - Failed to start: SocketListener0@0.0.0.0:4444
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Selenium is already running on port 4444. Or some other service is.
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.start(SeleniumServer.java:491)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.boot(SeleniumServer.java:300)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.main(SeleniumServer.java:245)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher.main(GridLauncher.java:97)
```

---

**UPDATE**

Regarding the second part of my question to run the selenium jar file, I tried the solution suggested by @acfreitas bellow but still got the same error message.

```
php-webdriver: (master)$ kill -9 {pid from selenium process}
bash: kill: {pid: arguments must be process or job IDs
bash: kill: from: arguments must be process or job IDs
bash: kill: selenium: arguments must be process or job IDs
bash: kill: process}: arguments must be process or job IDs
php-webdriver: (master)$ ps aux | grep selenium
ross      3451  0.0  0.7 2413344 45508 pts/12  Tl   14:53   0:00 java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar
ross      7874  0.0  0.0  15940   944 pts/12   S+   16:14   0:00 grep --color=auto selenium
php-webdriver: (master)$ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar
16:15:00.689 INFO - Launching a standalone server
16:15:00.767 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 24.75-b04
16:15:00.767 INFO - OS: Linux 3.13.0-46-generic amd64
16:15:00.833 INFO - v2.45.0, with Core v2.45.0. Built from revision 5017cb8
16:15:00.984 INFO - Default driver org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped: registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}] does not match with current platform: LINUX
16:15:01.062 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
16:15:01.063 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
16:15:01.064 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
16:15:01.065 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
16:15:01.065 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
16:15:01.142 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@2a4c6a7d
16:15:01.143 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
16:15:01.156 WARN - Failed to start: SocketListener0@0.0.0.0:4444
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Selenium is already running on port 4444. Or some other service is.
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.start(SeleniumServer.java:491)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.boot(SeleniumServer.java:300)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.main(SeleniumServer.java:245)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher.main(GridLauncher.java:97)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two question here:

### First question

Your composer can't resolved the dependencies from  facebook/webdrive and [minimum stability flags](https://igor.io/2013/02/07/composer-stability-flags.html). 
Add `"minimum-stability": "dev"`

```
{
  "name": "facebook/webdriver",
  "description": "A php client for WebDriver",
  "keywords": ["webdriver", "selenium", "php", "facebook"],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver",
  "type": "library",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/issues",
    "forum": "https://www.facebook.com/groups/phpwebdriver/",
    "source": "https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.19",
    "facebook/webdriver": "dev-master"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*",
    "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "2.*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": ["lib/"]
  }
}
```

and run

```
$ php composer.phar install
```

### Second question

The port default Selenium is `4444`. The `Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Selenium is already running on port 4444. Or some other service is.` said that selenium already running. If you want run again, you can kill process as:

```
$ $ ps aux | grep selenium
root   3997  2.6  3.2 465024 33336 pts/0    Sl+  15:40   0:00 java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar
$ kill -9 3997
```

See that ***3997*** is about [pid](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ps-kill-and-nice-to-manage-processes-in-linux) from selenium process. Change for your pid.

or run selenium with this command:

```
$ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -role hub -port 4441
```

So, you should edit the host port in your tests. More information, you can see [doc](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp#specifying-the-port)

Comment: Thanks @acfreitas, the first part of your answer fro composser seemed to work but I got a message at the end saying `Package dflydev/markdown is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use michelf/php-markdown instead.
`, is that important?  Why does the GitHub Readme page not advice to use `"minimum-stability": "dev",` as you suggested?  The second part of your answer did not work :( I updated my question with the terminal output for this.

Comment: @CreedBratton, change {pid from selenium process} as [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/kill-process-in-linux-or-terminate-a-process-in-unix-or-linux-systems/) and I edited the answer. About composer, you can see in [doc](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability) for more information. This log said that dependencies was deprecated. If you are using [markdon](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), you can add [markdown](https://packagist.org/packages/michelf/php-markdown) in your composer.json. Else, you can continue.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to comment on why GitHub Readme page didn't advise to use "minimum-stability": "dev". It's because it's a bad idea/practice to do so.

> One way to fix the problem would be to just lower your
>   minimum-stability down to "dev". But that's usually a really bad idea,
>   because it applies to all constraints and as a result you will get
>   unstable versions of all packages.
>
> So please, don't do that.

(see https://igor.io/2013/02/07/composer-stability-flags.html)